# How can I use "-In" operator in powershell? String constains another string or not?

Tags: powershell

I would like to use to chech if a string consains another string or not.

For example:

```
if("234" -In "1234 56)
{
#do something
}
```

It seems it works.

```
But if I have variables how can I do this?
For example: 
$a = "234"
$b = "123456"
```

Comment: What about `if("123456" -like "*234*") {#do something}`?

Answer (score 3):

Operator **-In** searches if values is exists in compared array/collection. Like so:

```
$Arr = 1,2,3,4,5

5 -in $Arr
True

6 -in $Arr
False
```

**-In** operator is available in Powershell version 3 and above.

Comment: As a side note to that.  `-contains` is available in earlier versions (And so will be found on XP and on Windows 7 that doesn't have all updates).  The only difference in syntax is to swap the value and array/collection

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for operator -match :

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" -match "def" ##returns $True
```

Check [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) for more info.

Comment: What about if it has commas? For example: $s = "abc def ghi"

Comment: Operator '-match ' matches a regex, so as long as you have proper regular expression, it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

one example with variables could be like this.

```
$string1 = "234"    
$string2 = "123456"

    foreach($s in $string2)
    {
        if($s.Contains($string1))
        {
           Write-Host "It does contain"
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "does not contain"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `-in` is not the solution to your problem.  However, in future if you do need information about PowerShell operators, a good place to start is in the built-in help:

```
Get-Help about_Operators
```

This topic gives a general overview, and points to more-specific topics.  In this case, you can get more help on `-in` from:

```
Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators
```